# I want to know which sde corresponds to which physical hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-disk, raid1

I want to know which sde corresponds to which physical hard disk. I noticed that the sde is unallocated space (sde is logical drive where is 2 hard disks with RAID 1),so I want to remove the hard disks from server to use them as a spare parts in the future.

Notes:

1. operating system is RHEL 6.6.
2. I use Fujitsu Rx 300s8 server with sas 6/1gb raid controller.
3. 10 hard disks installed ,I use raid 1 for every 2 hard disks so total of logical group is 5.

[image]

Comment: `hdparm -I /dev/sde` will tell you a lot of info, including the model name & serial number, which you could match to those from the label.

Comment: Another thing that you can do is use the Fujitsu iRMC web interface to to see which physical drives are included in the logical drive for the RAID array and match up the information.

Comment: Thanks Nasir, Fujitsu iRMC gives a lot of useful informations but didn't give me which logical drive is sde and that's my problem.

Comment: Thanks mosvy , hdparm didn't give any helpful information like serial number. Because sde is logical drive (RAID1 array with 2 hard disks ) not physical drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

Your system has a real hardware RAID controller. That means only the RAID controller has the information you're asking for. To get that information, you need a vendor-specific utility that can query the settings of the RAID controller. The most lightweight of those would be the `storcli` command-line utility.

You can get the utility from [Fujitsu's support pages](https://support.ts.fujitsu.com). If you haven't been there before, it will automatically ask you to select a product. Otherwise it might remember the product you've viewed the last time: click on "Select a new Product" in that case.

You can select the right product in several ways: if you can disclose the product serial number, then the support web server will automatically show you the correct drivers based on the configuration of the system when it left the factory. (You can get the serial number with `dmidecode -s system-serial-number`.)

Otherwise, you might select "Browse for product" -> "Fujitsu server PRIMERGY" -> "PRIMERGY RXxxx" -> finally your server model "PRIMERGY RX300 S8". Once you are on the correct support page for your hardware model, select "More Details" under "Downloads".

Then you'll need to choose the operating system you're downloading drivers for: select either "Red Hat Enterprise Linux (x86)" or "Red Hat Enterprise Linux (x86_64) depending on whether your installation is 32-bit or 64-bit, respectively.

Once you've chosen the correct OS, go to the Applications tab on the resulting page, then open the "SAS RAID" category, and the "RAID Ctrl SAS 6G 1GB (D3116C)" sub-category. Find the "LSI SAS MegaRAID controller configuration utility - StorCli (LINUX)" line and click on "Direct download". You should get a ZIP file that contains a RPM file and some license and README files. Install the RPM (the command is in the README file), and you'll have the `storcli` and `storcli64` commands available. On a 64-bit OS, you'll probably need the `storcli64` version.

You can find a good overview of `storcli` commands at: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/StorCLI

More info with output examples here:
http://fibrevillage.com/storage/710-storcli-virtual-drive-command-examples

Assuming that your system has just one RAID controller (and so the controller you want to query is number 0), and there are no other disk devices, you'll probably need this command:

```
storcli64 /c0/v4 show all
```

The `PDs for VD 4` listing will tell you the slot numbers (the `Slt` field) and serial numbers of the physical disks of the 5th logical disk device: `sda` would be VD 0, etc.

The other software package available from the download page is called "ServerView RAID Manager". It would provide a Java-based web GUI in port 3173 of the server (= another thing that needs to be secured on an Internet-connected server), and a simplified command-line tool `amCLI`. 
With it, you can view all the RAID controller configuration information with `amCLI -l all`. You can find the instructions for this package in the corresponding sub-category of the "Documents" tab of the download page.

Comment: telcoM Thank you very much , your answer helped me .

Comment: If my answer was satisfactory, please click on the green check-mark next to the top of my answer: only the poster of the question can do that, and it’s even better than a regular upvote (which you might not be able to do yet).